# Move MySQL database to another server

Tags: mysql, linux

I need to move 20 Gb MySQL database from on Debian server to another. The problem is that there is no way to create its backup since there are almost no free HDD space on the source server. What would you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks everybody. Eventually I found the simplest solution [here](http://christiank.org/wp/2010/12/pipe-a-gzipped-mysql-dump-over-ssh/):

```
mysqldump -u MYSQL_USERNAME -p YOUR_DATABASE | gzip -c | ssh USERNAME@YOUR_TO_HOST 'cat > ~/dump.sql.gz'
```

Answer (score 4):

Percona XtraBackup can stream the backup over the network directly to the second server, and use no disk space on the source server.

See examples here:

http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/howtos/recipes_ibkx_stream.html

Answer (score 1):

MySQL Workbench has a built in tool that allows for very easy database migration. Simply temporarily enable remote connection on the two mysql databases and run from your local computer. This assumes you have access to a windows to run the tool from.

Allow remote access (someone correct me if i am wrong on that code). Make sure to turn it off when done.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO  'USERNAME'@'IP'  IDENTIFIED  BY  'PASSWORD';
```

Link to workbench
http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/tools/workbench/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to copy a MySQL database to another host without creating a local backup. The fastest way is probably to just copy all table definition, data and index files from the database directory to the other host. For MyISAM tables, the relevant files are those with extensions of .myi, .myd and .frm. For InnoDB, the files are ibdata (may also be ibdata_[suffix]), .idb and .frm. This method is officially supported by MySQL, see the documentation on [MyISAM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/copying-databases.html) and [InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-migration.html).

You can also run `mysqldump` from either host and stream the data directly into a new database. This method is also outlined in the documentation link.

Comment: Copying the data files is only valid for MyISAM tables.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, not sure why I didn't find this before, but: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-migration.html

Comment: that is true, transportable tablespaces was introduced in 5.6.  It's important to note that it is a somewhat more delicate operation for InnoDB.